# Scrolling log text in a Fyne TextGrid automatically

Tags: go, fyne

I'm trying to use a widget to display text which will scroll vertically as more text is added.

I'm unable to figure out how to get the text to scroll, though. The closest I've come is enabling scrolling, but you have to manually scroll down as text is appended. I haven't found a way to "lock" resizing; if don't put the TextGrid into a scroll container, the application seems to jump in size outside the boundary of the monitor.

Is there a way to get the TextGrid to scroll automatically?

```
    appClient := app.New()
    winWindow := appClient.NewWindow("Test")

    txtEntry := widget.NewEntry()
    txtStatus := widget.NewLabel("Status")
    txtResults := widget.NewTextGrid()
    txtResults.ShowLineNumbers = true

    btnQuit := widget.NewButton("Quit", func() {
        appClient.Quit()
    })
    btnQuit.Resize(fyne.NewSize(300, 300))

    cntScrolling := container.NewScroll(txtResults)
    cntButtons := container.NewGridWithColumns(4, layout.NewSpacer(), layout.NewSpacer(), layout.NewSpacer(), btnQuit)
    cntContent := container.NewGridWithRows(4, txtEntry, txtStatus, cntScrolling, cntButtons)

    winWindow.Resize(fyne.NewSize(1200, 600))
    winWindow.SetContent(cntContent)

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case strMessage := <-chnSendMessageToClientWindow:
                txtResults.SetText(strings.TrimPrefix(txtResults.Text()+"\n"+strMessage, "\n"))
                cntScrolling.Refresh()
            }
        }
    }()

    winWindow.ShowAndRun()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re probably looking for `cntScrolling.ScrollToBottom()`
When you wrap items in a scroll container there is no way to automatically scroll down or right when new content is added, but that line will do that each time you add content.

> I haven't found a way to "lock" resizing

Items in fyne are typically either minimum size (pack the content) or expand to fill the space. It is unwise to “lock size” somewhere in between because then the UI does not scale well across screens and window sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to that function; I'll take a look and test it out. Regarding the locking of size, is this also true for the application window? The application would suddenly resize larger than the monitor itself, so I can't even see part of the display or the buttons (one of which is the quit button...). Making do with the dynamic resizing of items within the primary application window is one thing, but having the application jump size is "interesting" for users to tolerate. (I'll probably use a separate question for that after the scroll issue)

Comment: A Window will attempt to fit the content. If you make the content huge then the window may get larger than you want (this is OS dependent).
If you want to display massive content then using `container.Scroll` is probably advisable.